# Applying stored procedures to SQL table to assign NULL values

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, null

I have a large SQL table which consists of "#N/A N/A" across multiple columns/rows.

How do I apply a stored procedure to turn all of these values into NULL values.

Comment: Are you sure it needs to be a stored procedure?  Wouldn't a simple update statement work?

Comment: Ideally I would like to use a piece of code whereby i don't have to specify the columns but rather apply the formulation to all the columns in the table? Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
create table ##test2
(a1 varchar(200))
insert into ##test2 values('#N/A N/A'),('abc'),('#N/A N/A')
select  * from ##test2

create proc dbo.ex1 as
begin
set nocount on

update ##test2 set a1=null where a1='#N/A N/A'
end

select * from ##test2
```